# Creating several grids at a time

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix that contains start and end points, and want to create grids in-between these. For now this is linear, but I would like to be able to also use this for nonlinear grids (of my own).

```
test = np.array([[0.1, 0.5], [0.0001, 0.9]]) #start points in row 0, end points in row 1
nL = 10 # number of grid points
np.hstack((np.linspace(0.1, 0.0001, nL).reshape((-1,1)), np.linspace(0.5, 0.9, nL).reshape((-1,1)))) 
# expected output. 
array([[ 0.1  ,  0.5  ],
       [ 0.089,  0.544],
       [ 0.078,  0.589],
       [ 0.067,  0.633],
       [ 0.056,  0.678],
       [ 0.045,  0.722],
       [ 0.033,  0.767],
       [ 0.022,  0.811],
       [ 0.011,  0.856],
       [ 0.   ,  0.9  ]])
```

For now, this relies on stacking `linspace` which is not really nice and readable. What's a more clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What about exploiting `.T`:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([[0.1, 0.5], [0.0001, 0.9]]) # start points in row 0, end points in row 1
nL = 10 # number of grid points
x1 = np.hstack((np.linspace(0.1, 0.0001, nL).reshape((-1,1)),
                np.linspace(0.5, 0.9, nL).reshape((-1,1))))

# shorter version:
x2 = np.vstack([np.linspace(t[0], t[1], nL).T for t in test.T]).T

print(np.all(x1==x2)) # gives True
```